# How to make window.open() pop up a sticky popup?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a program where i use popup with the help of javascript window.open(). It is working fine but i want to make it sticky popup. Here i try make you understand what i'm looking for. For ex. I have page called add_data.php in this page i have button called upload picture when i click upload picture button a popup appears where pircture can b uploaded. But i dont want to user allow to do anything on other tabs until upload picture tab is completed or closed. In other words i want to stick the picture upload popup.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make a new browser window modal.

People doing this sort of thing generally use DOM manipulation to display new UI elements on top of the current page (which block accesses to the rest of the page using overlays and methods to disable access with the tab key etc).

There are [lots of JavaScript libraries / UI frameworks that provide a modal](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript%20framework%20with%20modal&t=h_&ia=web).